# Multiple authors with same affiliation in ACM SIGCHI Conference format

Tags: acm, author, affiliation

I am trying to reach a layout similar to the one used in [this](https://trackr-media.tangiblemedia.org/publishedmedia/Papers/642-OTIzM/Published/PDF), or [this](http://morphingmatter.cs.cmu.edu/~morphin5/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/paper037.pdf) paper, with the [ACM SIGCHI Conference format](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).

Mainly I want to get a list of authors on the same line with commas between their names, without using a single /author{} block, so to not break the metadata extraction tools.

Same goes to the list of emails with same endings. How can I reach a format with {first1.last1,first2,last2}@email?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid ACM explicitly discourages this format.  They wanted me to make it impossible.  Well,  with TeX nothing is completely impossible, but I tried to make it hard.

Comment: I know it's discourages to do anything else than the standard format. But I see it is accepted in many recent papers, and it is my preferred formatting. So I thought there must be a way to do it without messing up the metadata extraction scrapers.